# C# VS - When one radio button is checked, uncheck another

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a form, on which i placed 2 radio buttons. My issue is I need it to function in a way where if one is clicked, the other will be unclicked. I have the following code however it gets stuck in an inifinite loop once you do the first click and I do understand why. Wanted to see if any of you guys know how to go about making this in c#? I'm fairly new to c#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        radAllCols.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.radAllCols_Checked);
        radSelCols.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.radSelCols_Checked);
    }

    private void radAllCols_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radAllCols.Checked == true)
        {
            radAllCols.Checked = false;
            radSelCols.Checked = true;
        }
    }

    private void radSelCols_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radSelCols.Checked == true)
        {
            radSelCols.Checked = false;
            radAllCols.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: RadioButtons placed in the same parent control (like a panel) behave this way by default.

Comment: You need to put the radio buttons in a container such as group box or panel.

Comment: You can place both the radio buttons in the panel or groupbox and then you don't need to bind any events and at a time only one of the them would be selected. You could get the radio button which is checked by using the Checked Property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the radio buttons have different `RadioGroup` values you have to first, unregister the Checked event, change the Checked property value and re-register the Checked event.

```
private void radAllCols_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radAllCols.Checked == true)
    {
        radAllCols.CheckedChanged -= new 
                 EventHandler(this.radAllCols_Checked);
         radSelCols.CheckedChanged -= new 
                 EventHandler(this.radSelCols_Checked);
        radAllCols.Checked = false;
        radSelCols.Checked = true;
        radAllCols.CheckedChanged += new 
                 EventHandler(this.radAllCols_Checked);
         radSelCols.CheckedChanged += new 
                 EventHandler(this.radSelCols_Checked);
    }
}

private void radSelCols_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radSelCols.Checked == true)
    {
        radAllCols.CheckedChanged -= new 
                 EventHandler(this.radAllCols_Checked);
         radSelCols.CheckedChanged -= new 
                 EventHandler(this.radSelCols_Checked);
        radSelCols.Checked = false;
        radAllCols.Checked = true;
        radAllCols.CheckedChanged += new 
                 EventHandler(this.radAllCols_Checked);
         radSelCols.CheckedChanged += new 
                 EventHandler(this.radSelCols_Checked);
    }
}
```

The code above is for very custom scenarios and should be avoided as much as possible. The radio boxes should behave the way you want automatically. Make sure you have the same `RadioGroup` property value on both of them.

Comment: Problem with this, is once I run the Form, and lick one of the radio buttons, the other is selected and then no matter what i do i cannot select the other. It's as though it locks it?

Comment: Never mind, i think this was because i didn't delete the `EventHandler` i had in `Form 1`. Seems to be working fine now!

Answer (score 2):

RadioButtons placed in the same parent control (like a panel) behave this way by default.

**There is no need to use a checked event for this.**

Setting values of the `radAllCols.Checked = true` property fires the `radAllCols_Checked` event this causes your infinite "loop"

Since you are trying to uncheck the same radioButton to checked

```
private void radSelCols_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radSelCols.Checked == true)
    {
        radSelCols.Checked = false; // reversed
        radAllCols.Checked = true; // reversed
     }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i get the infinite loop part, trying to figure out how to get past this so that it only occurs when use checks/unchecks one of these boxes?

Comment: @user6144226 Am i missing something here? The `radiobuttons` are on the form itself. Is there any need for the `CheckChanged` event? Won't they do the expected behavior without that

Comment: @SBozhko can you just comment out the lines in `public Form1()
    {  }` You should get what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you use ***GroupBox Container Element***  for same Radio Buttons that you want select one of them, you don`t need handle check state of Radio Buttons manually, When you select a Radio Button all the other Radio Buttons in the same group will be unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Your rest of the code is fine but you need to change your code in Checked methods() as mentioned below to prevent infinite loop and then it will work fine:

```
private void radAllCols_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   radAllCols.Checked = !radSelCols.Checked;
 }

private void radSelCols_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   radSelCols.Checked = !radAllCols.Checked;
 }
```